# "Could not find table 'microposts'" issue with Michael Hartl Tutorial Chapter 10

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm trying to create a micropost model in chapter 10 of michael hartl's tutorial and I cannot get past the rspec tests.

**Here's what I've done:**

1. `rails generate model Micropost content:string user_id:integer`
2. `rm -f spec/factories/microposts.rb`

**This is the db migrate file:**

```
class CreateMicroposts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :microposts do |t|
      t.string :content
      t.integer :user_id

      t.timestamps
    end
    add_index :microposts, [:user_id, :created_at]
  end
end
```

**This is the model spec for micropost:**

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe Micropost do

  let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
  before do
    # This code is not idiomatically correct.
    @micropost = Micropost.new(content: "Lorem ipsum", user_id: user.id)
  end

  subject { @micropost }

  it { should respond_to(:content) }
  it { should respond_to(:user_id) }
end
```

**And then I did:**

1. `bundle exec rake db:migrate`
2. `bundle exec rake test:prepare`

**My error message are these:**

```
1) Micropost
     Failure/Error: @micropost = Micropost.new(content: "Lorem ipsum", user_id: user.id)
     ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid:
       Could not find table 'microposts'
     # ./spec/models/micropost_spec.rb:8:in `new'
     # ./spec/models/micropost_spec.rb:8:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

2) Micropost
     Failure/Error: @micropost = Micropost.new(content: "Lorem ipsum", user_id: user.id)
     ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid:
       Could not find table 'microposts'
     # ./spec/models/micropost_spec.rb:8:in `new'
     # ./spec/models/micropost_spec.rb:8:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

**Schema**

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(:version => 20130801225814) do

  create_table "users", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "email"
    t.datetime "created_at",                         :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                         :null => false
    t.string   "password_digest"
    t.string   "remember_token"
    t.boolean  "admin",           :default => false
  end

  add_index "users", ["email"], :name => "index_users_on_email", :unique => true
  add_index "users", ["remember_token"], :name => "index_users_on_remember_token"

end
```

I can't figure out the problem because I'm pretty confident I followed the steps in chapter 10 precisely. Maybe it's something from before?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Your db:migrate didn't take, since the microposts definition is not in the schema. Do you have the output from executing that migration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it should be `bundle exec rake db:test:prepare` instead of `bundle exec rake test:prepare`

Comment: Hey, thanks for your response. Unfortunately I still have the same errors after using the code you suggested.

Comment: can you share the generated schema?

Comment: What do you mean by generated schema? Sorry, I'm a beginner.

Comment: This file: db/schema.rb

Comment: The schema file does not have a microposts table. This means that something went wrong with the migration. Did you get any error when you ran rake db:migrate?

Comment: thank you, I was able to fix it. There was an error I didn't notice, I had to remove an "end" in the sample_data.rake file. Thanks again! @davidrac